# Get Culture Display Name in its language

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am getting the current culture as follows:

```
var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DisplayName;
```

The problem is that I always get the name in English:

- EN becomes English
- PT becomes Portuguese instead of Português
- FR becomes French instead of ...

How can I get the DisplayName of a Culture in that specific language?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: Display will display the name in the language of the current .net framework location. Use Name or NativeName.

Comment: Neither of those work ... They both give me in English

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to display the `NativeName` instead of the `DisplayName`.

Comment: It does not work ... I get English anyway ... Maybe because my OS is in English?

Answer (score 10):

If one just tries to get the localized language of a culture (without the country) one can use this snippet:

```
CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

string nativeName = culture.IsNeutralCulture
    ? culture.NativeName
    : culture.Parent.NativeName;
```

If one will use a specific localized language name, one can use this:

```
string language = "es-ES";
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(language);

string nativeName = culture.IsNeutralCulture
    ? culture.NativeName
    : culture.Parent.NativeName;
```

If one wants to have a title case name (e.g. Français instead of français), use this line:

```
string result = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(nativeName);
```

As a method:

```
private static string GetTitleCaseNativeLanguage(string language)
{
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(language);

    string nativeName = culture.IsNeutralCulture
        ? culture.NativeName
        : culture.Parent.NativeName;

    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(nativeName);
}
```

Or as an extension method:

```
public static string GetNativeLanguageName(this CultureInfo culture, bool useTitleCase = true)
{
    string nativeName = culture.IsNeutralCulture
        ? culture.NativeName
        : culture.Parent.NativeName;

    return useTitleCase
        ? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(nativeName)
        : nativeName;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`DisplayName` will be shown in the language of the location of the current .NET framework.

You can use `NativeName` (or maybe even just `Name` I've not tried this) instead of `DisplayName`, that should do the trick.

**Edit**

After testing this with the following code:

```
// set the current culture to German    
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
var native = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NativeName;
var display = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DisplayName;
var name = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
```

The results were:

> native = "Deutsch (Deutschland)"
>
> display = "German (Germany)"
>
> name = "de-DE"